# How to center imageview on actionbar with icons inflated by menu

Tags: android, android-layout

My imageview was centering when I had one icon to the right and a back button to the left, but now with two icons on the right it is offset by one of the icons, was wondering if I can do something in xml to keep the imageview centered?

Here is my xml and I tried layout gravity center, and gravity center neither worked.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/action_bar_background"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is the menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_comments"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_comments"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: can you post some image: your result and your expected result

Comment: post an image of what you want so it will be easy to solve.

Comment: I figured out the issue, it is because the Image is filling the space available which is being thrown off by the icon, so trying to figure out a better solution, I just used margin left for now